# Why does `getResourceAsStream` sometimes load a resource even when there is a typo in the resource path?

Tags: jar, jvm

I have a Jar (we'll call it `a.jar`) with a resource in it at path `foo/bar.txt` and a function as follows:

```kotlin
object FooBarLoader {
    fun loadFooBarText() = javaClass.getResourceAsStream("foo//bar.txt")
        ?.bufferedReader()
        ?.readLines()
        ?.joinToString("\n")
}
```

When I test the function in a unit test (JUnit 4, running with Gradle 6), it loads the text from the resource file despite the obvious typo (the `//` in the middle of the resource path).

I also have a CLI application (in `b.jar`) that has a dependency on `a.jar`. When the CLI application calls `loadFooBarText()`, it got a null result due to the resource not being found. This was fixed by fixing the typo (`//` -> `/`) in the function in `a.jar`. No other changes were needed to fix it.

So, my question is why did the *wrong* path work in one situation (unit tests of `a.jar`) and not the other (call from `b.jar`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you run the unit test with `a.jar` ?  Just run it in your IDE or use command `java -jar a.jar` ?

If you ran it just in IDE，I think difference is the `search path` between local files and `zip` files .

Your first application searches the file in your `target directory` and the second application searches it in the `jar` which is a compressed file.

When searching files in local path, command will be changed to right one by system.

The two commands below are the same in both Windows/Linux.

```
cd work//abc/ddd

cd work/abc/ddd
```

But when searching files in a `jar` file which is actually compressed `zip` file, path should be a restrict written or else the program will find nothing.

Comment: I ran using `gradlew test` with no special configuration of the test task. Your answer certainly sounds plausible, but I’m going to see if I can confirm it.

Comment: @MatthewPope gradlew use the compiled classes and resources in local path and the reading operation is just like what  we can do in terminal.